# Why should an Exchange identity token be secure?

Tags: javascript, outlook, exchange-server, office-addins

I have a problem by understanding the authentication mechanism for microsoft outlook add-ins. I don't understand how an Exchange identity token can be secure if everyone has access to the key which was used to sign the jwt?!
For example if an outlook add-in would be installed on exchange online, the key can be found on https://outlook.office365.com/autodiscover/metadata/json/1. So everyone could generate a token using this public key.
Would be great if someone could help me to understand it. I went through the documentation over and over again, but it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: The *public* key, not the *private* one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know how often the public key is changing? Is there a difference between exchange online and on-prem?

Comment: I don't know. Probably very rarely.